# Zuul and JSESSIONID

Tags: netflix-zuul, jsessionid

I am using Zuul edge server to proxy requests to a bunch of session scoped controllers and stateless REST end points. Has anyone figured out a way to add the `JSESSIONID` in the subsequent request while proxying requests to session scoped controllers?

The issue I am facing is that Zuul does not manage the `JSESSION` id and cookies in general this causes the Session scoped controllers to create a new instance for every request.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know cookies are by default blocked. But you can change it in configuration.

I think more information you can find in following [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html) parts:

- Cookies and Sensitive Headers
- Ignored Headers